# PL/SQL Developer - empty object list

Tags: plsql-developer

I'm using PL/SQL Developer v9, brio intelligence 6.6 and on another computer SQL Developer v7. On version 7 everything is ok. My table objects are 'expanding' shows all avaiable databases.
[image]

In version 9 object does not develop - as if it were empty. When I use BRIO all databases are avaiable...
[image]
So there is some problem with PL/SQL Developer but I can't figure it out ;\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. A little ridiculous but it was enough to change the 'current user' to 'all users' tab objects
[image]